# Como alterar CSV em Python e Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Sou iniciante em Python e preciso de uma ajuda.

Tenho um arquivo em csv que possui apenas uma coluna com dados de idade.

Preciso transformar os números inteiros em intervalos, como "ate_21_anos", "ate_24_anos", etc.

O problema é que não consigo comparar um int e retornar uma string.

Se possível, gostaria de obter esse resultado utilizando pandas.

Até o momento, tentei dessa forma:

```
import pandas as pd
dados = pd.read_csv('Alunos.csv', delimiter=';', usecols=['IDADE_INGRESSO']
for x in dados:
   if x <= 21:
   return "menor_21"
dados
```

Sei que está incompleto e com erros, pois sou realmente novato.

Abaixo há uma amostra da base que estou usando:

[image: Base de origem]

Aqui são os resultados que pretendo obter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, editei a pergunta. Espero que agora esteja mais claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer com o pandas é usar a função `apply()`.

```
df['Intervalo']=df['IDADE_INGRESSO'].apply(lambda x: 'menor_21' if x<21 else ('menor_24' if x<24 else 'maior_24'))
```

Se a sua regra for mais complicada, como querer um intervalo de 18, 21, 24,... , também é possível criar uma função de decisão e aplicar com o `apply()`.

```
def define_intervalo(num):
    for faixa in [21,24]:
        if num < faixa:
            return 'menor_{}'.format(faixa)
    return 'maior_{}'.format(faixa)

df['Intervalo'] = df['IDADE_INGRESSO'].apply(define_intervalo)
```

Comment: Deu certo utilizando o apply(), sem precisar da função. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar a função `np.where()` para isso.

Supondo que tem uma coluna `idade` dentro de um *pandas Dataframe* com nome `df`:

```
import numpy as np

df['faixa_etaria'] = np.where(df.idade<=21,'até_21',np.where(df.idade<=24,'entre 21 e 24',np.where(df.idade<=35,'entre 24 e 35','mais de 35')))
```

Desse modo terá 3 faixas etárias com esse condicional encadeado!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Ao tentar desta forma, recebo o erro "    ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given". Atualizei a pergunta. Por favor, verifique se está mais claro

Comment: Gerei aqui da minha parte e não teve nenhum problema. Veja o exemplo:

 df = pd.DataFrame ({'idade' : [25,32,21,20,18,34,45]})

Aplicando o código que te mandei voce fica com as duas colunas, se precisar dropar a de idade é só usar .drop()

Answer (score 0):

Uma ideia..

Você pode usar o comando cut do pandas.

Para demonstrar como usa, em vez de importar uma lista, fiz com uma lista.

```
import pandas as pd

idades = [21, 33, 15, 21, 28, 60, 35, 19, 41, 10, 18, 38, 22,]
bins = [0, 21, 24, 100]
idades_ingresso = pd.cut(idades, bins)
idades_ingresso
```

[(0, 21], (24, 100], (0, 21], (0, 21], (24, 100], ..., (24, 100], (0, 21], (0, 21], (24, 100], (21, 24]]
Length: 13
Categories (3, interval[int64]): [(0, 21] < (21, 24] < (24, 100]]

Foram criadas 04 categorias/ faixas

```
idades_ingresso.categories
```

IntervalIndex([(0, 21], (21, 24], (24, 100]],
closed='right',dtype='interval[int64]')

Você poderia contar os valores que estão em cadas faixa, que no seu caso, seriam as idades.

```
pd.value_counts(idades_ingresso)
```

(24, 100]      6

(0, 21]        6

(21, 24]       1

dtype: int64